# Does condition expression of for loop changes after each iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, core-js

I'm trying to write a function `decreasingOrder` which takes a positive integer as input and return an `array` of its digits in decreasing order.

e.g., `decreasingOrder(1234)` Should give `[4,3,2,1]`.

```
function decreasingOrder(n) {
  let unarr = [...`${n}`].map(i => parseInt(i)); //Unordered Array of Digits
  let oarr = []; //Ordered Array of Digits
  
  for(let j=0; j<unarr.length; j++){
  let max = Math.max.apply(Math, unarr);
  oarr.push(max);
  unarr.splice(unarr.indexOf(max), 1); //delete element from array
  }

  return oarr;
}

console.log(decreasingOrder(1234));
//Expected [4,3,2,1], Instead got [4,3]
```

- I think, deleting element using `splice` method also reduces the number
  of iteration.
- I also tried `delete` operator but get `[4, NaN, NaN, NaN]` (because `Math.max([undefined])`).
- When I tried with specific number instead of `unarr.length` in `condition` expression for `for` loop, it works fine!

So when I use `splice` method to delete elements it reduces the `unarr.length` and when I tried to keep `unarr.length` constant using `delete` operator it gives `NaN`, what should I do? Is there any other way to write to the same function? I'm beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: If you are using digits, you might as well handle the number as a string.

Comment: You should be cautious when using `splice`. It'll delete the element from the actual array. So the length of the array gets changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is `unarr.splice(unarr.indexOf(max), 1)` inside loop.

> By taking your example of `console.log(decreasingOrder(1234))`. In the first cycle the highest number from the array is found and is removed from the array and pushed to new array.

> At the end of the first cycle the outputs will be `unarr = [1, 2, 3]`, `oarr = [4]` and `j=1`

> Likewise after second loop `unarr = [1, 2]`, `oarr = [4, 3]` and `j=2`. Now the loop condition `j < unarr.length` is not satisfied hence the loop breaks. So the output will be `[4, 3]`.

Instead you can use the below utility for your requirement.

```js
function decreasingOrder(n) {
  let unarr = [...`${n}`].map(i => parseInt(i)) //Unordered Array of Digits

  return unarr.sort((a,b) => b-a)
}

console.log(decreasingOrder(1234))
```

Hope this helps.